# I cannot load Next.js image in Direct Path with external site image

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-images

I use Next.js v13.4.4.

Error is here, and of course, it doesn't from a static image.

```
Error: An object should only be passed to the image component src parameter 
if it comes from a static image import. 
It must include height and width. 
Received {"src":"https://lh3.googleusercontent.com
```

My next config is following:

```js
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "**.googleusercontent.com",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/**",
      },
    ],
  },
```

My Client Component is here:

```js
"use client"
import Image from "next/image"

export default function ImageComponent(src: any) {

  return <Image src={src} alt="user-image" height={38} width={38} fill />
}
```

Comment: Did you try restart the Nextjs server?

Comment: Can you show the component too?

Comment: Did you try restart the Nextjs server?  > Yes, I did.

Comment: Can you show the component too?  > I added Client Component.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. I forgot {} bracket in argument.
That's why there is another "src" inside argument's "src.
Here is correct code.

```js
"use client"
import Image from "next/image"

export default function ImageComponent({src}: any) {

  return <Image src={src} alt="user-image" height={38} width={38} fill />
}
```